# logstash create index in elasticsearch based on the log file path

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

i want to create multiple index based on the string contains in the path .

this is my beat file :

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
     paths:
       - /home/admin/script_logs/**/*.log
    .......
    ........
```

this is my logstash conf

```
output {

    if  [log][file][path]  =~ /^*scripts*$/ {
         elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
            index => "logstash-scripts-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
         }

    }
    else if [log][file][path] =~ /^*system*$/ {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
            index => "logstash-system-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
    else{

        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
            index => "logstash-normal-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }

  }
```

here the if conditions `([log][file][path]  =~ /^*scripts*$/ and [log][file][path] =~ /^*system*$/ )` are not working, here i am trying to search for a string in the file path, but it is not working.
So somebody please help me.

Comment: Your regexes look wrong, I think they should be written like this: `/^.*scripts.*$/` & `/^.*system.*$/`.

Comment: You can also use something like `if "scripts" in [log][file][path] { your output }`.